# GEKKO MPC Solver generating @error: Inequality Definition invalid inequalities: z > x < y minimize<generatorobject<..>

Tags: gekko

I am learning to use the GEKKO MPC solver, and write the above code as test. After multiple attempts, I am still not able to get it running and keep getting the following exception.

```
APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 minimize<generatorobject<genexpr>at0x7f8cb1a1c950>
 STOPPING . . .
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e92d32444662> in <module>
    122 # Solver
    123 m.options.IMODE     = 6 # control
--> 124 m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
    125 
    126 # Plot the results

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gekko/gekko.py in solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2183             #print APM error message and die
   2184             if (debug >= 1) and ('@error' in response):
-> 2185                 raise Exception(response)
   2186 
   2187             #load results

Exception:  @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 minimize<generatorobject<genexpr>at0x7f8cb1a1c950>
 STOPPING . . .
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Here is the code I wrote:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = GEKKO()           
ALPHA               = 0.5
NUM_FANS            = 8         # MAX Number of fans
NUM_PUMPS           = 1         # MAX number of pumps
n_steps             = 25
m.time              = np.linspace(0, n_steps - 1, n_steps)
DELTA_TOP           = 5         # 5 degC
DELTA_HOT           = 5         # 5 degC
DELTA_PU            = 0.05      # 0.05 p.u
fan_powers          = np.array([145, 130, 120, 100, 500, 460, 430, 370, 860, 800, 720, 610, 1500, 1350, 1230, 1030])   #  kW
pump_powers         = np.array([0.43, 1.07, 2.95, 6.92, 8.83])                                                         #  kW
C_base              = NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers) + NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers)                                  #  kW
x_state             = np.array([61.29027692, 70.15582365,  0.86972331])
u_state             = np.array([5, 1.00, 1500.00, 0.43])  # np.array(pd.DataFrame([[5, 1.00, 1500.00, 0.43]], columns=['nfans', 'npumps', 'fpower', 'ppower'] )) #np.array([1.00, 1500.00, 0.43])  

ref_state   = pd.DataFrame([
                [0,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.637217',  50.949829,  56.055570, 0.70],
                [1,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.719390',  46.113708,  48.741882, 0.60],
                [2,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.754899',  43.921465,  49.425708, 0.60],
                [3,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.782037',  44.792515,  49.895490, 0.60],
                [4,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.831646',  45.814439,  51.055404, 0.60],
                [5,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.910940',  46.677830,  51.900248, 0.60],
                [6,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.951684',  47.500278,  52.609172, 0.60],
                [7,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.050460',  48.187270,  53.240813, 0.60],
                [8,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.126050',  48.866124,  53.806335, 0.60],
                [9,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.205533',  49.395292,  54.303250, 0.60],
                [10,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.237825',  49.908234,  54.732465, 0.60],
                [11,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.261200',  50.315668,  55.112417, 0.60],
                [12,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.303079',  50.750658,  55.793464, 0.70],
                [13,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.370096',  51.341523,  57.619243, 0.70],
                [14,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.463300',  51.666736,  58.602764, 0.80],
                [15,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.524749',  52.738678,  60.785766, 0.80],
                [16,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.552913',  53.460458,  62.226178, 0.90],
                [17,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.589561',  55.055422,  64.867184, 0.90],
                [18,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.633709',  56.231096,  66.286857, 0.90],
                [19,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.671211',  57.876352,  67.644409, 0.90],
                [20,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.708004',  59.015503,  68.931404, 0.90],
                [21,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.729763',  60.586943,  70.227752, 0.90],
                [22,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.753146',  61.809524,  71.492779, 0.90],
                [23,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.779459',  63.232974,  72.710304, 0.90],
                [24,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.808419',  64.324357, 74.556550, 1.05]], columns=['id', 'sampdate', 'optopoil', 'ophotspot', 'opload'])

# Initial State at i = 0
puload_0    = x_state[2]
hotspot_0   = x_state[1]
topoil_0    = x_state[0]

# Initial Controls at i =0
n_fans_0  = u_state[0]
n_pumps_0 = u_state[1]
Cw_0 = u_state[0] * u_state[2]
Cp_0 = u_state[1] * u_state[3]

# References
ref_puload  = np.array(ref_state['opload'])
ref_hotspot = np.array(ref_state['ophotspot'])
ref_topoil  = np.array(ref_state['optopoil'])

# Controlled variables
tophigh = m.Param(value = ref_topoil)
toplow = m.Param(value =  ref_topoil  - DELTA_TOP)

hothigh = m.Param(value=ref_hotspot)
hotlow = m.Param(value=ref_topoil  - DELTA_TOP)

pulow = m.Param(value=ref_puload)
puhigh= m.Param(value=ref_puload  - DELTA_PU)

puload     = m.CV (value = np.array([puload_0]*n_steps),  lb = ref_puload  - DELTA_PU,   ub = ref_puload)
hotspot    = m.CV (value = np.array([hotspot_0]*n_steps), lb = ref_hotspot - DELTA_HOT,  ub = ref_hotspot)
topoil     = m.CV (value = np.array([topoil_0]*n_steps),  lb = ref_topoil  - DELTA_TOP,  ub = ref_topoil)

m.Equations([topoil >= toplow, topoil <= tophigh])
m.Equations([hotspot >= hotlow, hotspot <= hothigh])
m.Equations([puload >= pulow, puload <= puhigh])

puload.STATUS   = 1
hotspot.STATUS  = 1
topoil.STATUS   = 1

# Manipulated variables
fan_low   = m.Param(value = np.zeros(n_steps))
fan_high  = m.Param(value =  np.array([NUM_FANS]*n_steps))
pump_low  = m.Param(value = np.ones(n_steps))
pump_high = m.Param(value =  np.array([NUM_PUMPS]*n_steps))

Cw_low    = m.Param(value = np.zeros(n_steps))
Cw_high   = m.Param(value= np.array([NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers)]*n_steps))

Cp_low    = m.Param(value = np.ones(n_steps))
Cp_high   = m.Param(value = np.array([NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers)]*n_steps))

n_fans      = m.MV (value = np.array([n_fans_0]*n_steps),  lb = np.zeros(n_steps),  ub = np.array([NUM_FANS]*n_steps))
n_pumps     = m.MV (value = np.array([n_pumps_0]*n_steps), lb = np.ones(n_steps),   ub = np.array([NUM_PUMPS]*n_steps))
Cw          = m.MV (value = np.array([Cw_0]*n_steps),      lb = np.zeros(n_steps),  ub = np.array([NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers)]*n_steps))
Cp          = m.MV (value = np.array([Cp_0]*n_steps),      lb = np.ones(n_steps),   ub = np.array([NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers)]*n_steps))

m.Equation([n_fans >= fan_low, n_fans <= fan_high])
m.Equation([n_pumps >= pump_low, n_pumps <= pump_high])
m.Equation([Cw >= Cw_low, Cw <= Cw_high])
m.Equation([Cp>= Cp_low, Cp <= Cp_high])


n_fans.STATUS = 1
n_pumps.STATUS = 1
Cw.STATUS = 1
Cp.STATUS = 1

# Objective Function
Fuv = m.Var(value=0)
m.Minimize(Fuv = sum(ALPHA * (Cw[i] + Cp[i]) / C_base
                                        + (1 - ALPHA) * (
                                           pow ((ref_puload[i] - puload[i]) / DELTA_PU, 2)
                                        +  pow ((ref_hotspot[i]- hotspot[i]) / DELTA_HOT, 2)
                                        +  pow ((ref_topoil[i] - topoil[i]) / DELTA_TOP, 2)
                                        )) for i in range(n_steps))

# Solver
m.options.IMODE     = 6 # control
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gekko does the time indexing. Here is a modified version of the code that solves successfully. Solution was found by first solving without the inequalities as:

```py
#%% Solve without inequalities
m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
```

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  6.51001E+07  0.00000E+00
    1  1.19052E+16  0.00000E+00
    2  7.77312E+01  0.00000E+00
    3  7.49548E+00  0.00000E+00
    4  7.49548E+00  0.00000E+00
    6  7.49548E+00  0.00000E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.043000000000000003 sec
 Objective      :  7.4954845726019945
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

and then using that solution to initialize the case with the inequalities:

```py
#%% Turn on DOF and include inequalities
n_fans.STATUS = 1
n_pumps.STATUS = 1
Cw.STATUS = 1
Cp.STATUS = 1

m.Equations([topoil >= toplow, topoil <= tophigh])
m.Equations([hotspot >= hotlow, hotspot <= hothigh])
m.Equations([puload >= pulow, puload <= puhigh])

m.Equations([n_fans >= fan_low, n_fans <= fan_high])
m.Equations([n_pumps >= pump_low, n_pumps <= pump_high])
m.Equations([Cw >= Cw_low, Cw <= Cw_high])
m.Equations([Cp>= Cp_low, Cp <= Cp_high])

m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
```

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  7.91421E-02  7.49900E+03
    1  7.70285E-02  1.30000E-09
    2  7.70285E-02  2.00000E-10
    3  7.70285E-02  2.00000E-10
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.033999999999999996 sec
 Objective      :  0.07702852753968847
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the complete script:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)           
ALPHA               = 0.5
NUM_FANS            = 8         # MAX Number of fans
NUM_PUMPS           = 1         # MAX number of pumps
n_steps             = 25
m.time              = np.linspace(0, n_steps - 1, n_steps)
DELTA_TOP           = 5         # 5 degC
DELTA_HOT           = 5         # 5 degC
DELTA_PU            = 0.05      # 0.05 p.u
fan_powers          = np.array([145, 130, 120, 100, 500, 460, 430, 370, 860, 800, 720, 610, 1500, 1350, 1230, 1030])   #  kW
pump_powers         = np.array([0.43, 1.07, 2.95, 6.92, 8.83])                                                         #  kW
C_base              = NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers) + NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers)                                  #  kW
x_state             = np.array([61.29027692, 70.15582365,  0.86972331])
u_state             = np.array([5, 1.00, 1500.00, 0.43]) 

ref_state   = pd.DataFrame([
                [0,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.637217',  50.949829,  56.055570, 0.70],
                [1,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.719390',  46.113708,  48.741882, 0.60],
                [2,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.754899',  43.921465,  49.425708, 0.60],
                [3,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.782037',  44.792515,  49.895490, 0.60],
                [4,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.831646',  45.814439,  51.055404, 0.60],
                [5,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.910940',  46.677830,  51.900248, 0.60],
                [6,   '2022-08-30T19:33:07.951684',  47.500278,  52.609172, 0.60],
                [7,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.050460',  48.187270,  53.240813, 0.60],
                [8,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.126050',  48.866124,  53.806335, 0.60],
                [9,   '2022-08-30T19:33:08.205533',  49.395292,  54.303250, 0.60],
                [10,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.237825',  49.908234,  54.732465, 0.60],
                [11,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.261200',  50.315668,  55.112417, 0.60],
                [12,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.303079',  50.750658,  55.793464, 0.70],
                [13,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.370096',  51.341523,  57.619243, 0.70],
                [14,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.463300',  51.666736,  58.602764, 0.80],
                [15,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.524749',  52.738678,  60.785766, 0.80],
                [16,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.552913',  53.460458,  62.226178, 0.90],
                [17,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.589561',  55.055422,  64.867184, 0.90],
                [18,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.633709',  56.231096,  66.286857, 0.90],
                [19,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.671211',  57.876352,  67.644409, 0.90],
                [20,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.708004',  59.015503,  68.931404, 0.90],
                [21,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.729763',  60.586943,  70.227752, 0.90],
                [22,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.753146',  61.809524,  71.492779, 0.90],
                [23,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.779459',  63.232974,  72.710304, 0.90],
                [24,  '2022-08-30T19:33:08.808419',  64.324357, 74.556550, 1.05]], \
                           columns=['id', 'sampdate', 'optopoil', 'ophotspot', 'opload'])

# Initial State at i = 0
puload_0    = x_state[2]
hotspot_0   = x_state[1]
topoil_0    = x_state[0]

# Initial Controls at i =0
n_fans_0  = u_state[0]
n_pumps_0 = u_state[1]
Cw_0 = u_state[0] * u_state[2]
Cp_0 = u_state[1] * u_state[3]

# References
ref_puload  = m.Param(np.array(ref_state['opload']))
ref_hotspot = m.Param(np.array(ref_state['ophotspot']))
ref_topoil  = m.Param(np.array(ref_state['optopoil']))

# Controlled variables
tophigh = m.Param(value = ref_topoil)
toplow = m.Param(value =  ref_topoil  - DELTA_TOP)

hothigh = m.Param(value=ref_hotspot)
hotlow = m.Param(value=ref_topoil  - DELTA_TOP)

pulow = m.Param(value=ref_puload)
puhigh= m.Param(value=ref_puload  - DELTA_PU)

puload     = m.Var(value = puload_0)
hotspot    = m.Var(value = hotspot_0)
topoil     = m.Var(value = topoil_0)

# Manipulated variables
fan_low   = m.Param(value = 0)
fan_high  = m.Param(value = NUM_FANS)
pump_low  = m.Param(value = 1)
pump_high = m.Param(value = NUM_PUMPS)

Cw_low    = m.Param(value = 0)
Cw_high   = m.Param(value= NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers))

Cp_low    = m.Param(value = 1)
Cp_high   = m.Param(value = NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers))

n_fans      = m.MV(value = n_fans_0,  lb = 0,  ub = NUM_FANS)
n_pumps     = m.MV(value = n_pumps_0, lb = 1,  ub = NUM_PUMPS)
Cw          = m.MV(value = Cw_0,      lb = 0,  ub = NUM_FANS * np.max(fan_powers))
Cp          = m.MV(value = Cp_0,      lb = 1,  ub = NUM_PUMPS * np.max(pump_powers))

# Objective Function
Fuv = m.Intermediate(ALPHA * (Cw + Cp) / C_base
        + (1 - ALPHA) * ((ref_puload - puload) / DELTA_PU)**2
        +  ((ref_hotspot- hotspot) / DELTA_HOT)**2
        +  ((ref_topoil - topoil) / DELTA_TOP)**2)
m.Minimize(Fuv)


#%% Solve without inequalities
m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)


#%% Turn on DOF and include inequalities
n_fans.STATUS = 1
n_pumps.STATUS = 1
Cw.STATUS = 1
Cp.STATUS = 1

m.Equations([topoil >= toplow, topoil <= tophigh])
m.Equations([hotspot >= hotlow, hotspot <= hothigh])
m.Equations([puload >= pulow, puload <= puhigh])

m.Equations([n_fans >= fan_low, n_fans <= fan_high])
m.Equations([n_pumps >= pump_low, n_pumps <= pump_high])
m.Equations([Cw >= Cw_low, Cw <= Cw_high])
m.Equations([Cp>= Cp_low, Cp <= Cp_high])

m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tired it and it ran ...however with a noticeable error depicted in the following:--------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
....
 
 files(5): ERROR: terminated read
   of file ctl.t0
   because variable order is no longer consistent.
 files(84): ERROR: terminated read
   of file ctl.dxdt
   because variable order is no longer consistent.
 Variable time shift OFF
 Number of state variables:            888
 Number of total equations: -          720
 Number of slack variables: -          336     What could be causing such outcome?

Comment: Gekko uses the prior solution to initialize the next solution attempt. If returns this error if the number of variables changes. This doesn't happen with adding additional equations or objectives but the inequalities do add an additional slack variable each. As long as the 2nd problem converges, you can ignore this error (use m.solve(`disp=False`) to not see it). It just means that only some of the variables were initialized.